# Using Excel's SUMPRODUCT with SEARCH and ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a row of cells that contain comma delimited strings like so:

[image]

I have figured out how to add the first character of each string using this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(C2:G2,SEARCH(",",C2:G2,1)-1)))`

Now, I would like to extend the formula to the cell `AA2`, like so

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(C2:AA2,SEARCH(",",C2:AA2,1)-1)))`

however, I cannot seem to get the it to ignore empty cells - it throws a `#VALUE!` error. I realize that I could simply update the formula each time I enter data in the subsequent cells, but that's not exactly efficient. I assume this throws an error because the SEARCH function returns a null value.

How might I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below modified formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(C2:AA2&"0,",SEARCH(",",C2:AA2&"0,",1)-1)))`

For right side you can use `MID` like below and check:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(C2:AA2&".0",SEARCH(",",C2:AA2&",.0",1)+1,99)+0))`

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried to use RIGHT as well to get the number after the comma, but no such luck. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @codeEnthusiast I have tested second formula and it works at my end without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of searching for the comma is not needed if you only want to add the **first character** of each cell.  Just grab the left-most single character.

Say we may have data from **A1** to **Z1** that may include some blank cells.  Pick a cell and enter the ***array formula***:

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(A1:Z1)>1,--LEFT(A1:Z1),0))
```

for example:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.